# How do I perform a cumulative sum on groups of numbers in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Question: How to complete and simplify the following syntax so as to achieve the desired output?

Desired Output:

```py
[16.0, 22.0, 26.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0]
```

Current syntax:

```
a = [16.0, 6.0, 4.0, 15.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0]  #---> there is 3 sets of data in here, 
                                                           assuming the number of sets will 
                                                           change at different point in time

 b = 3    #----> this represents the number of dataset in "a", and will to change at different   
                 point in time

c = []

for idx, i in enumerate(a[0:3]):
    if idx == 0:
        c.append(i)
    else:
        c.append(a[idx-1] + i)

for idx, i in enumerate(a[3:6]):
    if idx == 0:
        c.append(i)
    else:
        c.append(a[idx-1] + i)        

for idx, i in enumerate(a[6:9]):
    if idx == 0:
        c.append(i)
    else:
        c.append(a[idx-1] + i) 
        
print(c)
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can calculate the numbers 0, 3, 6, 9 given `b = 3`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 OP wants a cumulative sum in groups of three.

Comment: @DreamyDeerz were you helped by either of the posted answers? If so, please upvote and mark one as correct so that this post can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using numpy (highly recommended anytime you're working with numerical data):

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([16.0, 6.0, 4.0, 15.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0])
>>> b = 3

>>> np.cumsum(a.reshape(-1, b), axis=1).flatten()
array([16., 22., 26., 15., 18., 21.,  5.,  6.,  8.])
```

This assumes that `a` can be broken up evenly into `b`-sized chunks, of course.

### Steps

Reshape into rows, where each row is the subgroup of `b` number of items (the `-1` tells numpy to figure out how many rows are necessary):

```py
>>> a.reshape(-1, b)
array([[16.,  6.,  4.],
       [15.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  1.,  2.]])
```

Cumulative sum per row:

```py
np.cumsum(a.reshape(-1, b), axis=1)
array([[16., 22., 26.],
       [15., 18., 21.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  8.]])
```

Flatten back into a list:

```py
>>> np.cumsum(a.reshape(-1, b), axis=1).flatten()
array([16., 22., 26., 15., 18., 21.,  5.,  6.,  8.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `step` argument in `range()` to move `b` steps at a time, in this case, we will get index (0, 3, 6). Then, for each index, use another for loop to perform the cumulative sum. Here's the code:

```
a = [16.0, 6.0, 4.0, 15.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0]
b = 3
c = []
for i in range(0, len(a), b):
    total = 0
    for j in range(b):
        total += a[i + j]
        c.append(total)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[16.0, 22.0, 26.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0]
```